# What is the terminology of this subgroup of $GL_{n+m}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups

Let $$K=\{g\in GL_{n+m}(\mathbb{R}): gJg^t=J\}$$
where $J=\text{diag}(I_n,-I_m)$ with $I_n$ and $I_m$ identity matrices. What is $K$ called? How is it used in math?

Comment: @Max: that is not correct.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Read it too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the [indefinite orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $O(n, m)$. Its most famous appearance is in special relativity, where the group $O(3, 1)$ naturally appears as symmetries of Minkowski space. It's also related to hyperbolic geometry.